# Swift - Optimizing UI animation fades

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, string

I have the following code which accomplishes exactly what I need. I had to specifically target these UI elements rather than using a UIView fading overtop of it all due to the nature of the app.

```
    @IBAction func hidecontrols(_ sender: UIButton) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
    self.brightnesstitle.alpha = 0
    self.brightnesslbl.alpha = 0
    self.brightnesssldr.alpha = 0
    self.kelvintitle.alpha = 0
    self.kelvinlbl.alpha = 0
    self.kelvinsldr.alpha = 0
    self.greentitleminus.alpha = 0
    self.greentitleplus.alpha = 0
    self.greenzerobtn.alpha = 0
    self.greensldr.alpha = 0
    self.greensldrdiv.alpha = 0
    self.hidecontrolsbtn.alpha = 0
    }
}
```

I'd like to optimize it, but I wasted hours trying so I left it as is. I originally tried a for loop in which I put the various UI names into an array, but no matter what I tried, It wouldn't pass through the string properly and claimed that .alpha wasn't a member of the String.

Is there a way to assign a custom value to each UI element I want to affect and then call the fade animation to every element that has that value?

Answer (score 0):

Aha, I can think of two ways:

Simple version. If all the variables above are instances of `UIView` or subclasses of `UIView`, then you can do:

```
let fadingViews: [UIView] = [brightnesstitle, brightnesslbl, ...]
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) { fadingViews.forEach { $0.alpha = 0 } }
```

If some of them are not `UIView` instances, then you can define a protocol like this

```
protocol Fadable {
    var alpha: CGFloat { get set }
}

extension UIView: Fadable {}
extension MyClass: Fadabale {}
```

and then do

```
let fadables: [Fadable] = [brightnesstitle, brightnesslbl, ...]
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) { fadingViews.forEach { $0.alpha = 0 } }
```